# Need to activate mysql

Tags: mysql, apache, window

I recently downloaded xampp in which mysql was a component. I had difficulty getting apache and my mysql to run but I finally managed. Now when I go to the status page I see that mysql is not activated. Yet in task manager it is running. Inside services under administrative tool on windows 8.1 it is running. How do I activate mysql? I tried using the command line. `>bin mysqld` Yet on the status page it is still showing "not activated". How do I activate mysql. I appreciate any help on this problem. Thank you. Here is the status page.

```
XAMPP Status
This page offers you one page to view all information about what's running and working, and what isn't working.


Component   Status  Hint    
MySQL database   DEACTIVATED        
PHP  ACTIVATED      
HTTPS (SSL)  ACTIVATED      
Common Gateway Interface (CGI)   ACTIVATED      
Server Side Includes (SSI)   ACTIVATED      
SMTP Service     DEACTIVATED        
FTP Service  ACTIVATED      
Tomcat Service   ACTIVATED


Some changes to the configuration may sometimes cause false negatives. All reports viewed with SSL (https://localhost) do not function!
```

Comment: I changed the port in mysql from 3306 to 3312 because it didn't run on 3306 port. I wonder if that's the problem with mysql  status being "not activated". Yet it is running. Does running equate to activated?

Comment: I'm uisng xampp. My apache is running but mysql wasn't running on port 3306. So I tried port 3312. It still didn't run. The problem was that I had installed MySql 5.6 prior and it was blocking port 3306.  I deleted MySql 5.6. and in the xampp controll I put mysql back to port 3306 and put it's path in the system environmentals.  Then I went to the command line and entered the command to install mysql and the service was successful. Now in the control panel in Administrative Services in services I right clicked Mysql to start it and got the message error-1067-process terminated-unexpectedly-0

Comment: what you said above does not make any sense...Xampp has mysql installed with it..."why would you go to the command line and install mysql" again...if I were you at this point..I would start from scratch by uninstalling any mysql and xampp version from comp and reboot...then do a fresh install of just Xampp

Comment: I was just desperate, so I thought that going to the command line I could either restart or install mysql. Something happened because I got the message that the service was successful. Then I tried to start mysql and got the 1067 error message. I had already uninstalled wamp and then installed Mysql alone. After that I installed xampp.

Comment: I went ahead and deleted Xampp and reinstalled it. Now everything is working fine. Thanks for the help.